# Share to view page title

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Im getting error:
`Undefined variable: pageTitle (View: /.../resources/views/layouts/auth.blade.php)`

Line: `<title>{{ $pageTitle . ' | ' . $settings->company_name }}</title>`

I'm using fortify auth and I want to share page title to auth blade.

My `__construct` code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    \View::share('pageTitle', 'test');
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

I've tried also like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    view()->share('pageTitle', 'test');
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

I'm using laravel 8.

Comment: the constructor of what?

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
View::share('key', 'value');
```

is supposed to be inside a `ServiceProvider`'s (like `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`) `boot()` method [like in the example](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views), not inside a constructor for what I'm assuming is a `Controller`.

Comment: I have each controller same construct but with different value. Ex.: `View::share('pageTitle', 'Login');` - For login controller. `View::share('pageTitle', 'Register'); `- For registration page... If I run in boot it shows every page same title and its not what I need. After I changed UI Bootstrap Auth for UI Bootstrap Fortify it doesnt work anymore like this...